Prove or disprove that the envelope of some chords of a conic section is another conic section
The problem is as follows:
Let $\Gamma$ be an ellipse and $A$ is a point in the interior of $\Gamma$. Let $B,C$ be two moving points on $\Gamma$ such that $AB\perp AC$. Prove or disprove that the envelope of $BC$ is a conic section.
The picture is as follows
It seems that is the envelope is another ellipse, $A$ is one of the the Foci.

My attempt is like this. We know that for a tangent of $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$ on $(x_0,y_0)$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 & y_0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
A & B & D\\
B & C & E\\
D & E & F
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
So if the coefficient is $Ux+Vy+1=0$, then $(U,V)$ is on a conic section. Therefore, we set $\Gamma$ to be $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0$, $A(0,0)$, and set $B(x_1,y_1),C(x_2,y_2)$. The line is $x(y_1-y_2)+y(x_2-x_1)=x_1y_2-x_2y_1$ So we need to find some constant $a',b',c',d',e',f'$ (which only depends on $A,B,C,D,E,F$) which always
$$a'(x_1-x_2)^2+2b'(x_2-x_1)(y_1-y_2)+c'(y_1-y_2)^2+2d'(x_1-x_2)(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)+2e'(y_1-y_2)(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)+f'(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2=0$$
With constraints $ax_1^2+2bx_1y_1+cy_1^2+2dx_1+2ey_1+f=0$, $ax_2^2+2bx_2y_2+cy_2^2+2dx_2+2ey_2+f=0$, and $x_1x_2+y_1y_2=0$.
But I am unable to find it, since the $y_1^2y_2^2$ terms in $(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2$ (using $x_1x_2+y_1y_2=0$) is tough to think... May I ask is there any ideas...?

May I ask where you came across this problem?

@Pranay It is from a common problem where $\Gamma$ is a circle. Now I tried to generalize to ellipse, and it turns out to be still true though.

I see. Can you please give some reference for the circle case?

@Pranay It is an article in Zhihu (a website in Chinese.) https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/640378607

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - 1 = 0$ be the equation of the original ellipse. Let $P=(u,v)$ be a point in the ellipse other than $A = (x_0,y_0)$ and let $\ell$ be a line through $P$, say $y-v = m(x-u)$, where $m$ is a free parameter (the slope). It intersects the ellipse at two points $Q=(x_1,y_1)$ and $R=(x_2,y_2)$, where $x_{1,2}$ are the two real solutions to the quadratic equation
$$
f(x,m(x-u)+v) = \left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{m^2}{b^2} \right)x^2 + \frac{2m(v-mu)}{b^2}x + \frac{(v-mu)^2}{b^2} - 1 = 0.
$$
The angle $\theta$ subtended by the chord $QR$ at $A$ is given by
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{QA^2 + RA^2 - QR^2}{2 QA \cdot RA}.
$$

The hole (i.e., the region not covered by the line segment $BC$) is precisely the set of all $P$ for which $\theta$ is larger than $\pi/2$ for all $m$.

In other words, for all $m$, we want
$$
\cos \theta < 0 \implies QA^2 + RA^2 < QR^2.
$$
Expanding each side gives
$$
QR^2 = (x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2= (m^2+1) [(x_1+x_2)^2 - 4x_1 x_2],
$$
and
\begin{align}
QA^2 + RA^2 &= (x_1-x_0)^2 + (y_1-y_0)^2 + (x_2-x_0)^2 + (y_2-y_0)^2
\\
&= (x_1+x_2)^2 - 2x_1x_2 - 2x_0(x_1+x_2) + 2x_0^2
\\
&\qquad + (y_1 + y_2)^2 -2y_1y_2 -2y_0(y_1+y_2) + 2y_0^2
\\
&= (m^2+1) [(x_1+x_2)^2 - 2x_1x_2] - 2[x_0 + m(y_0 - v+mu)](x_1+x_2)
\\
&\qquad  + 2[(y_0-v+mu)^2 + x_0^2].
\end{align}
Therefore, using Mathematica for the cumbersome calculation, we have
\begin{align}
&QR^2 - (QA^2 + RA^2)
\\
&= -2(m^2+1)x_1x_2 - 2[x_0 + m(y_0 - v+mu)](x_1+x_2)
\\
&\qquad + 2[(y_0-v+mu)^2 + x_0^2]
\\
&= \frac{1}{b^2+a^2m^2} \Big[ \left(2 a^2 [b^2-(u-x_0)^2-y_0^2]-2 b^2 u^2\right)m^2
\\
&\qquad + 4 \left[a^2 v (u-x_0)+b^2 u (v-y_0)\right]m + 2 a^2 (b^2-v^2) - 2b^2 [(v-y_0)^2+x_0^2] \Big].
\end{align}
where we substituted $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1x_2$ from the quadratic equation above using Vieta's formulas. We want this quantity to be positive for all $m$, which means the discriminant of the quadratic inside brackets must be nonpositive. Using Mathematica again yields
\begin{align}
& 16 b^2 \left[(a^2 + b^2) (a^2 - x_0^2) - a^2 y_0^2\right] u^2 -32 a^2 b^2 x_0 y_0 \, u v + 16 a^2 \left[(a^2 + b^2)(b^2 - y_0^2) - b^2 x_0^2 \right] v^2
\\
&32 a^2 b^2 x_0 (x_0^2 + y_0^2 -a^2)\,u + 32 a^2 b^2 y_0 (x_0^2 + y_0^2-b^2)\, v - 16 a^2 b^2 (x_0^2 + y_0^2-a^2) (x_0^2 + y_0^2-b^2) \le 0.
\end{align}
While the expression looks quite cumbersome, the interesting thing to note is that it is quadratic in $u$ and $v$. Therefore, the boundary of this region is a conic section, answering the question in the positive.
Let us verify that it's an ellipse by computing its discriminant using Mathematica again. Indeed,
$$
-1024 a^2 b^2 (a^2 + b^2) (a^2 + b^2 - x_0^2 - y_0^2) (a^2 b^2 - a^2 y_0^2 - b^2 x_0^2)<0,
$$
which follows from
$$
a^2 > x_0^2,\qquad b^2 > y_0^2,\qquad a^2 b^2 - a^2 y_0^2 - b^2 x_0^2 = -a^2b^2 f(x_0,y_0) > 0,
$$
because $A$ is inside the original ellipse. Moreover, the foci can be computed using the approach given in this answer. They are
$$
A = (x_0,y_0),\qquad A' = \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}(x_0,-y_0).
$$
One can also compute the eccentricity of this ellipse using this expression from Wikipedia:
$$
e = \sqrt{\frac{b^4 x_0^2 + a^4 y_0^2}{a^2 b^2 (a^2 + b^2 - x_0^2 - y_0^2)}} < 1,
$$
where the inequality follows from
$$
[a^2 b^2 (a^2 + b^2 - x_0^2 - y_0^2)] - (b^4 x_0^2 + a^4 y_0^2) = -a^2 b^2 (a^2+b^2) f(x_0,y_0) > 0.
$$
Here's an example illustrating all the interesting objects.


Thank you so much for your kindly answer! I will review them later, but before that may I kindly ask, is there a way generalize to, for example, the case when A is outside the ellipse or even the $\Gamma$ is a parabola or hyperbola? Sorry for asking for more but it seems that this method can be generalized in that way though, but not easy...

@JetfiRex No worries! Yes, I think it generalizes rather straightforwardly to other conic sections. The essential idea is the one highlighted in the text in the blockquote. The rest is just very cumbersome algebra.
